# Neo4J (spring boot) with sealed classes in kotlin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, neo4j

I'm trying to create a somewhat generic implementation using kotlin and neo4j. My idea right now is that I want to have a GeoNode that can point to any kind of GeoJson feature (e.g. "Feature" or "FeatureCollection")

I tried to do this using kotlins sealed classes, e.g.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "type"
)
@JsonSubTypes(
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = GeoJsonFeature::class, name = "GeoJsonFeature")
)
@Node
sealed class FeatureContract(
    @GeneratedValue @Id var id: Long? = null,
    @Version var version: Long? = null
) {
    companion object {
        @JsonCreator
        @JvmStatic
        private fun creator(name: String): FeatureContract? {
            return FeatureContract::class.sealedSubclasses.firstOrNull {
                it.simpleName == name
            }?.objectInstance
        }

    }
}

data class GeoJsonFeature(
    val geometry: GeometryContract,
) : FeatureContract()


data class GeoJsonFeatureCollection(
    val features: List<GeoJsonFeature>,
) : FeatureContract()


// and the "GeoNode" that holds this

@Node
data class GeoNode(
    @Id val id: String,
    @Version var version: Long? = null
    @Relationship(type = "feature") var feature: FeatureContract?, // Should be either a featureCollection or a feature,

)
```

The idea is that I can have a point on a map that points to *any* kind of GeoJson.

It seems I am successful in serializing this and getting it into the Neo4J-db on write, however, on reading I get

`Failed to instantiate [FeatureContract]: Is it an abstract class?; nested exception is java.lang.InstantiationException`

The Jackson annotations are there cause I hoped they would help me (that Neo4J-OGM was using it under the hood) but it doesn't seem to have done the trick. I've read about Neo4JEntityConverters but I haven't understood how one can to this for a full object like this. Is there any good way to use sealed classes in kotlin with the neo4j-OGM for both serialization and deserialization?

Using spring boot 2.4.4 and spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j

Comment: There have been very recent fixes wrt inheritance handling. You might want to try Spring Data Neo4j 6.1.x (it should go GA today, you can try the RC in the meantime).